# Can we center align text in title tag?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code -

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Silly Title</title>    
  </head>
  <body>Silly Body</body>
</html>
```

How can I align the text in the window/tab's title to center?

Comment: On GUIs that display window titles centered, maybe. On GUIs that don't, why do you want to force it?

Comment: I have this problem too, sadly I believe this is not possible :( @BhabaniMishra

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you can't format the title in any way.

It's just information to the browser, that it will display outside the page itself. Typically it's shown in the name of the browser or on the tab for the page.

Comment: As I thought, sometimes we get weird requirements from clients :)

Answer (score -1):

If you have your `<title>` in a `<header>` tag, you can use this:

```
<style>
header {
text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I think he means the `<title>` that appears on the tab itself; in the `<head>` tag rather than `<header>`: thus it can't be formatted through CSS.

Answer (score -2):

I hope this answers your question;

```
<h2 style="text-align:center;">Sample text</h2>
```

Worked for me

Answer (score -3):

You can try this

```
          <Title><h2 align="center">Centered Heading</h2></Title>
```

I am not sure this will work or not but try.....
Check this tutorial

http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlattributes.php

Comment: You can't put any other HTML elements in a `<title>`, you can only put text.